# Warm Transfer Outbound call using Customer's phone number as Caller ID

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Deep into developing a custom contact center using Twilio to replace a current vendor.  Running into an issue with cold/warm transfers.  The 3rd parties we work with require that we call them on behalf of customers with the customer's phone number as the "from" number / caller id.

However, when attempting to add a new call leg to a conference, with the Customer's phone number as the "from" number, Twilio rejects the request even though the customer is currently in the conference call with the agent.  Error message is `"error": "HTTP 400 error: Unable to create record: The source phone number provided, <REDACTED>, is not yet verified for your account. You may only make calls from phone numbers that you've verified or purchased from Twilio...`

I clearly remember reading documentation when researching Twilio as a viable platform to build a replacement on top of that claimed the "from" number could be any Verified number, number purchased via Twilio, **OR a number affiliated with the conference requesting a new participant.**

Using the SHAKEN/STIR call token that is provided with inbounds will not correct the issue since our contact center also needs to transfers calls that start as outbound calls.

If there is absolutely no way to do this directly through Twilio base Voice API, are there any viable work arounds others have successfully used?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the Trusted Calling in Twilio if the call is incoming.
Also, you can't do this by using the participants api. You need to use calls api to create call by providing the call_token and then redirect the call to your exsiting conference.

```
{
  "Url" : "where call will be redirected to",
  "To" : "Destination number",
  "From": "Your client number",
  "CallToken" : "Token you received in the incoming call CallToken field"
}
```

To redirect your call to your existing conference, you can provide

```
<Response>
 <Dial><Conference> ExistingConference</Conference>
</Dial>
 </Response>
```